# Resolve many to many relationship

Tags: database

Does anyone have a process or approach to use for determining how to resove a many-to-many relationship in a relational database?  Here is my scenario.  I have a group of contacts and a group of phone numbers.  Each contact can be associated with multiple phone numbers and each phone number can be associated with multiple contacts.

A simple example of this situation would be an office with two employess (e1 & e2), one main voice line (v1), one private voice line (v2).  e1 is the CEO so they have thier own private voice line, v1, but they can also be reached by calling the main line, v2, and asking for the CEO.  e2 is just an employee and can only be reached by calling v2.

So, e1 should be related to v1 & v2.  e2 should be related to v2. Conversly, v1 should be related to e1 and v2 should be related to e1 & e2.

The goal here is to ge able to run queries like "what numbers can e1 be reached at" and "what employees can be reached at v2", etc..  I know the answer will involve an intermediate table or tables but I just can't seem to nail down the exact architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Employees:

```
eID, eName
1, e1
2, e2
```

PhoneNumbers:

```
pID, pNumber
1, v1
2, v2
```

EmployeePhones:

```
eID, pID
1, 1
1, 2
2, 2
```

then you inner join. if you need to find out what number(s) e1 can be reached at (t-sql):

```
SELECT E.eName, P.pNumber 
FROM   dbo.Employees E 
INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeePhones EP ON E.eID = EP.eID 
INNER JOIN dbo.PhoneNumbers P ON EP.pID = P.eID 
WHERE E.eName = 'e1'
```

I believe this should work (testing it right now...)

EDIT: Took me a few minutes to type up, sorry for duplication...

Comment: Ah, very good.  Thanks MK_Dev! That's the same answer I came up with so I feel much better about it.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need any temp tables for the query.  There is an intermediary table for the mapping.

> ```
> numbers_tbl
> -----------
> nid   int
> number    varchar
>
> employees_tbl
> -----------
> eid       int
> name  varchar
>
> employee_to_phone_tbl
> -----------
> eid       int
> nid       int
> ```

How can I call Bob?

> ```
> select *
> from employees_tbl e
> inner join employee_to_phone_tbl m
>   on e.eid = m.eid
> inner join numbers_tbl n
>   on m.nid = n.nid
> where e.name = 'Bob'
> ```

Who might pickup if I call this number?

> ```
> select *
> from numbers_tbl n
> inner join employee_to_phone_tbl m
>   on m.nid = n.nid
> inner join employees_tbl e
>   on e.eid = m.eid
> where n.number = '555-5555'
> ```

Comment: It looks like you need an intermediate table to me.  You used three tables in both your queries; numbers_tbl, employees_tbl, and employee_to_phone_tbl.  employee_to_phone_tbl would be what I call the intermediate table.

Comment: Yes, AviewAnew's first sentence is misleading.  Any many-to-many relationship should use a mapping table.

Comment: I did mean temp tables.  Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Others have explained the schema, but I'm going to explain the concept. What they're building for you, the table named EmployeePhones and employee_to_phone_tbl, is called an [Associative Entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), which is a type of [Weak Entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity).

A Weak Entity does not have its own natural key and must instead be defined in terms of its foreign keys. An Associative Entity exists for the sole purpose of mapping a many-to-many relationship in a database that does not support the concept. Its primary key is the grouped foreign keys to the tables it maps.

For further information on relational theory, see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model)

Answer (score 1):

1. Normalize
2. Best Practices on Referential Integrity
3. Check this  - http://statisticsio.com/Home/tabid/36/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/327/Need-Some-More-Sample-Databases.aspx

Comment: I think the example I gave was normalized as much as possible.  Two phone numbers and two employees.  This still does not address how to resolve a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @JediPotPie - I thought you were asking about architecture. I've read your comment on @MK_Dev. I can see that you are looking for the right *Query* - :-)

Answer (score 0):

After just a little more thought, here is what I came up with.  It probably goes along with the approach AviewAnew is thinking of.

employees

 id (index)

 name

numbers

 id (index)

 number

relations

employees.id (index)

numbers.id (index)

---

employees

  1 : e1

  2 : e2

numbers

  1 : v1

  2 : v2

relations

  1 : 1

  1 : 2

  2 : 1

Is this the best/only approach?

Comment: I would say that this approach was validated by MK_Dev above.  I would still be interested in any alternative ways, if there are any.

Comment: That's the best approach. See my post below on why