# Is there a more effective approach?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I recently started on creating a 'game' using PHP and a mysql database.
In this game, there are ships, which each player can build and control.

Right now I have several this set up in my database like this:

Ships table, contains there columns:
ID, name, credits cost, mineral cost, building time, description, speed, power, shield

The users table holds:
Ship_01_amount .... ship_08_amount

Where the number corresponds to the id of the ship.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, while not screwing things up.

Since now, if I wish to add a new ship, I have to alter my table.

Comment: What data does the users table contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to split the information about users and their ships into a third table. So you would have following tables:

```
t_ships: ship_id, name, credit_cost, mineral_cost, etc
t_users: user_id, name, etc
t_user_ships: ship_id, user_id, amount
```

This way when adding a ship you would just update the amount in the table t_user_ships.

Comment: And it would be beneficial to add indexes on `t_user_ships.user_id`, `t_users/user_id`, `t_user_ships.ship_id` and `t_ships.ship_id`

Answer (score 2):

It would help a lot to read up on database normalization. A good resource is as follows: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

While I know this is not answering your question directly, it will help with future predicaments like these. A Google search for "one to many mysql" or "many to one mysql" will pull up some useful resource.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Search for "what is many to many relationship".

Or check relevant question/answer: [resolve-many-to-many-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497395/resolve-many-to-many-relationship)

As all other have answered, a "middle" or "intermediate" table is the key to the solution. Any info (like the amount you have) about a particular ship of a particular user can be added as a field in that table. You could add colour-of-flag-raised, current-speed, captain's-name, date-of-first-sail, etc, whatever your game needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a [many-to-many relationship](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html#04) by creating a new table mapping between users and ships User_has_ship(userId, shipId).
You can use [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) in MYSQL to check that the user and the ship exists.

Altough check for user ships now needs a table join, so you have to do like this

```
SELECT * FROM User u, User_has_ship us WHERE u.Id = us.userId and userId=?
```

You should replace ? in userId with the id for the user you are currently checking.

Answer (score 0):

Make this basically into three tables.

- Table 1: Your current ships table.
- Table 2: User-Table (User-Data + User-ID and such).
- Table 3:
  Ships_User_META

  ```
  SHIP-ID | USER ID
  --------+--------
      1   |   1
      2   |   1
      3   |   1
      1   |   2
  ```

...and so on.

Therefore you can easily add and remove ships to users.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a table with unitary ship descriptions, and a table owning references to ships as columns. What you have here is relation between your user and ship references. Extending this requires altering your table schema. 
You advise the following :
Create a table user_ships with three columns :
- a user_id field, 
- a ship_id field,
- an amount field

Every time you need to know the amount of ships belonging to a single player you can do a SELECT on users, ships and user_ships tables joined with corresponding ids.
When a user builds a new model of ship, INSERT a record in user_ships table.
When a user loses or builds more ships, UPDATE the corresponding record.
That's it!