# PHP/MySQL - Multiple Selects For Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing an simple Musicians database that has a search function that will e-mail details of musicians to people when they search for a specific instrument in that database. I have people who play more then one instrument therefore I have 5 tables, instrument, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5.

I have a MYSQL query on my e-mail function but I cannot get it to search more then one table.

Here is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM instruments WHERE (instrument, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5) = '$search'";
```

Am I being stupid with my syntax or am I going about the wrong way with this.

Many thanks.

Comment: yeah, need to rethink your db there.

Comment: I thought as much! - I presume there is no way of salvaging my design because apart from this one part of the code it does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM instruments 
WHERE '$search' IN (instrument, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5)
```

? I assume this is what you want.

**But** a real solution would be to create a separate table with the instruments and not keep multiple columns for the same information.

You should have a table with musicians and one with instruments to hold general instruments and their info. And a 3rd one (used to resolve the many to many relationship between instruments and musicians) that only holds musician id and instrument id.

Here's a few useful links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
- [Resolve many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497395/resolve-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: This sounds positive, I already have the realtionship between instruments and musicians via unique ID, the instruments themselves are in a long list of a enum datatype, how would I generate IDs for them?

Comment: Also - THANK YOU for the above code, it seems to do the trick for now, this is only a simple database and I'm going to work on the database normalization later because obviously seems a much more efficient way.

Comment: @Toby When no ID is evident you can use autoincrement.

Comment: Yeah I already use autoincrement on both, thats how the instruments are linked to the musicians

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-tables.html

You should just have one table with fields instrument and email. It seems that is all you want.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be use 2 tables - Musicians and Instruments. Each row in Instruments table has a field 'musician_id', which refers to the corresponding musician. This is called 1-N relation.

Now, when you want to query the database, you do:

```
SELECT * FROM musicians m LEFT JOIN instruments i ON (m.id = i.musician_id) WHERE i.name = "Oboe";
```

This JOINS the two tables together, returning to you a row for every instrument a person plays.

Or, if you already know the Musician ID, query only instruments:

```
SELECT * FROM instruments WHERE musician_id = 123;
```

Comment: I already have two tables, people and instruments linked via unique IDs, i just had to create more then one instrument in the instruments table

Comment: Good, then the first query should do the job (I edited for an example). From the question I took that you had 5 tables.